# Peru Tourist Visa for Indian national in US with F-1 visa

Tags: usa, indian-citizens, peru, f1-visas

I am a Indian national currently residing in the US with a valid F-1 visa.
I am interested in travelling to Peru for a trip. Would I need a tourist visa?
Their embassy website does not give a clear picture of this.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** you need a tourist visa, visa requirements are tied to your citizenship and not any residence status in a third country. India is on the list of countries that are required to obtain a visa before travelling to Peru, according to the Peruvian [consulate](http://www.rree.gob.pe/servicioalciudadano/Documents/REQUERIMIENTOS_DE_VISAS_PARA_CIUDADANOS_EXTRANJERO.pdf) in San Francisco.

You can find the requirements for obtaining a Peruvian tourist [visa](http://www.consulado.pe/es/SanFrancisco/tramite/paginas/Issuance-of-Tourist-Visa.aspx) on their website.

Answer (score 1):

As of March 2017, any Indian national with a valid visa from United States, Canada, the United Kingdom, Australia or any Schengen State, can visit Perú visa-free [[1](http://www.andina.com.pe/ingles/noticia-peru-govt-waives-visa-for-indian-citizens-656746.aspx)][[2](http://busquedas.elperuano.com.pe/normaslegales/exoneran-del-requisito-de-visa-temporal-en-las-calidades-mig-decreto-supremo-n-006-2017-re-1493143-11/)].

I visited the country last month. Both me and my wife have a Canadian tourist and US work visa, immigration officer checked my US visa and my wife's Canadian visa.